# return each item by looping it inside a method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method which calls another method and that method loops each item and returns individual object to first method. I am not sure how to return each item by looping it inside a second method. My pseudo code is as below.

```
def process_episodes
  items << get_each_episodes_details(episode_doc)
end

def get_each_episodes_details(epi_doc)
  base_data = "Some common data related to the episodes"
  episodes = get_array_of_episodes_info_from_episode_doc(epi_doc) 
  #Finally return each episode details with base data
  episodes.each do |episode|
    return base_data + episode
  end
end
```

I was assuming that `return base_data + episode` would return each episode after iteration.

> But it did return only one item and exited from the method block. How
>   can I return multiple items so that if episodes array as 10 items,
>   then I need to return each item so that items array would contain 10
>   individual episode related information.

Comment: Use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of `each` (and don't return from within the loop)

Comment: I need to loop it 10 times on each episodes and then return each item

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: episodes_array = ["1","2,","3","4","5"]
base_info = "HBO returns back home"
episodes_array.each do |epi|
base_info + epi
end
Output show be as below
items[0] = "HBO returns back home 1"
items[1] = "HBO returns back home 2"
items[2] = "HBO returns back home 3"
items[3] = "HBO returns back home 4"
items[4] = "HBO returns back home 25

Comment: Don't paste that as a comment, edit your question instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will always return the first iterated episode and would never go to the next episodes as your returning as soon as you get in the loop.

You need some improvements in your code.

First of all, you have to return an array from the second function.

Like this

```
 def get_each_episodes_details(epi_doc)
   base_data = "Some common data related to the episodes"
   episodes = get_array_of_episodes_info_from_episode_doc(epi_doc) 
   #Finally return each episode details with base data
   episodes.map{|episode| base_data + episode} # this will return an array => [obj1,obj2, obj3...]
 end
```

Now your `items` will be an array of array `=> [[obj1,obj2..], [x1,x2..]]`

You can then call `flatten` on `items` to have flatten it so you don't get array of arrays. `items.flatten`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I dont want to return an array of items since it doesnt makes sense according to my scenario. I need to return each episode info with base data as a single item.

Comment: So items array would contain something like below items[0] = "HBO returns back home 1" items[1] = "HBO returns back home 2" items[2] = "HBO returns back home 3" items[3] = "HBO returns back home 4" items[4] = "HBO returns back home 5"

Comment: THis is a pseudo output. My original scenaior will have the metadata of each episodes with base data as a single item.

Comment: What does `episodes` contain if I were to consider the pseudo output as mentioned in the comment above??

Comment: It contains information of that particular episode which is of type Nokogiri::XML::Element

Comment: So basically I am creating indiviual XML metadata which has base data + episodes metadata so that I can process it in my first method

Comment: Im trying to understand still!! I see only two things, returning a single element or returning an array of elements. Im confused as to what exactly the requirement is ? :(

Comment: It should return each episode info to the first method one by one.

Comment: If you see the code you can see that episodes has a 10 episodes items. So afer iterating each episodes I am appending base_data to each episodes and then returning it to the called function so that the called function can process further with the returned output.

Comment: So I dont want to complete the episode iteration process  and pass the result as an array to the called function. After iteration once it is appended with base_data, it is ready for processing further and hence returning it..

Comment: Basically returning the output one by one.

Comment: I don't think thats even possible. If you call a function it needs to execute only after which the control passes back the calling function. What you're saying is that, When the second function is called, it returns the first element which should be made ready for processing, then it would return second element, then third and so on .. right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66402/discussion-between-rubyist-and-pamio-solanky).